# App identified me after buying a new device

Tags: ios, apple-id

I used a coupon on an iPhone X. When I tried to use it again I got a message telling me that I can't use the coupon on this device anymore. Few days ago I got an iPhone 13. I downloaded the same App, disabled iCloud for this App and then opened it. I tried to use the coupon and I got the same message. How is that possible? I used the same Apple ID on both devices, but so far as I know, iOS doesn't provide the App ID to the developers.

Comment: What kind of coupon?

Comment: uber eats coupon. This is not the problem, I am just wondering how I was identified

Comment: Does the coupon have a unique code? Are you only allowed to use one of those per Uber Eats account? Did you restore 13 from the X or enabvle iCloud syncing in general? There are a lot of details which might be relevant here.

Comment: The coupon is not unique, I was able to use it on the browser. Yes I restored the 13 using iCloud. Is there a unique ID that will be assigned to the iphone 13 if I sync it with the X?

Comment: Most likely the Uber Eats app preferences survived the transfer and have been picked up by the newly installed app.

Answer (score 1):

When you use coupons like that, apps will typically register that either locally in the Keychain of the device, or on their server (if you have logged in inside the app).

On your new device, you have then either logged into the app (and they will now who you are, and therefore whether or not you have used the coupon before) - or the app reads this information from the Keychain. As you have restored the new phone from a backup of your old phone, this Keychain data is transferred to the new phone - and the app then knows that you have spent the coupon earlier.

Comment: I used another account. I think as you said, the keychain is transferred to the new phone